# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: in struts 1.3.*

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, http-method

i have a action class which has the method i call but still i get the following exception

```
SEVERE: Action[/common/DepartmentAction] does not contain method named ''
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.action.DepartmentAction.(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping, org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

I am really confused why i get this kind of exception.

this is my action struts-config.xml :

```
<action path="/common/DepartmentAction"  name="SecurEyesForm" type="com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.action.DepartmentAction" scope="request" parameter="method" validate="false">
            <forward name="departmentHome" path="/WEB-INF/Masters/DepartmentMaster.jsp"></forward>            
        </action>
```

and this is my action class method :

```
public ActionForward goToHome(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        //call method to verify Pagetoken
        forwardRequestTo = "departmentHome";
        return mapping.findForward(forwardRequestTo);
    }
```

and this is how i call the method in java script :

```
function dataSave(){

                document.forms[0].action="DepartmentAction.htm";
                document.forms[0].method.value="saveDepartmentDetails";
                document.forms[0].target="workFrame";
                document.forms[0].submit();   
            }
```

what could be the problem?

i have used frameset.

Comment: function dataSave() is this valid method? and shouldn't your action class method be action if you are using Struts 1.2?

Comment: Is that a lookup dispatch action?

Comment: import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

Comment: What URL do see in your browser (it should be something like `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/DepartmentAction.htm?method=saveDepartmentDetails`). And you should a method with that name in your action class with `(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` parameters.

Comment: @BheshGurung, thanks for the comment, No URl is shown. i tried to set method="get" but still i don't get any URL

Comment: Any help please, I am in needed  of the same very badly.

Comment: @JavaQuestions the method named '' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In action tag parameter should be wrapped with goToHome ie., `parameter="goToHome"`